# React App Hosting - Host Prerequisites

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-hosting

Generic: What kind of services must a hosting vendor provide in order to make it possible to have a React app hosted?

More Specific: If I create a website with React and React Router, is it possible to deploy it by just uploading the bundled output folder? This could be for example a *dist* folder containing *index.html*, *bundle.js* and an *images* folder.
Could this be as simple as deploying a simple web page (like one built with plain HTML, CSS and JS)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure just do: npm run build

and you will have a folder with the static files. Upload those with your choice of file transfer method and set the permissions to the web host appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

100% Working Example.

React App Hosting in Firebase .

You can read this  [blog](https://easytechnolearn.blogspot.com/2019/05/fixed-blank-page-problem-after.html)

Host Your React Web App in few minutes.

*Command runnning in Wrong sequence =>*

> **firebase login**
>
> **firbase init**
>
> **firebase deploy**
>
> **npm run build**

*Command runnning in Correct sequence =>*

> **firebase login**
>
> **firbase init**
>
> **npm run build**
>
> **firebase deploy**